# how to make real time multi line chart using d3 where data is from api in json format

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts

I am trying to produce multi line real time chart with d3.js. And data i am getting is in json format by repeatedly calling api. How can i repeatedly call api. Here is my working code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .graph .axis {
        stroke-width: 1;
    }

    .graph .axis .tick line {
        stroke: black;
    }

    .graph .axis .tick text {
        fill: black;
        font-size: 0.7em;
    }

    .graph .axis .domain {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
    }

    .graph .group {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="graph"></div>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var limit = 60 * 1,
        duration = 750,
        now = new Date(Date.now() - duration)

    var width = 500,
        height = 200

    var groups = {
        current: {
            value: 0,
            color: 'orange',
            data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                return 0
            })
        },
        target: {
            value: 0,
            color: 'green',
            data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                return 0
            })
        },
        output: {
            value: 0,
            color: 'grey',
            data: d3.range(limit).map(function() {
                return 0
            })
        }
    }

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([now - (limit - 2), now - duration])
        .range([0, width])

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([height, 0])

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('basis')
        .x(function(d, i) {
            return x(now - (limit - 1 - i) * duration)
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d)
        })

    var svg = d3.select('.graph').append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height + 50)

    var axis = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'))

    var paths = svg.append('g')

    for (var name in groups) {
        var group = groups[name]
        group.path = paths.append('path')
            .data([group.data])
            .attr('class', name + ' group')
            .style('stroke', group.color)
    }

    function tick() {
    now = new Date()

        // Add new values
        for (var name in groups) {
            var group = groups[name]
            //group.data.push(group.value) // Real values arrive at irregular intervals
            group.data.push(20 + Math.random() * 100)
            group.path.attr('d', line)
        }

        // Shift domain
        x.domain([now - (limit - 2) * duration, now - duration])

        // Slide x-axis left
        axis.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .call(x.axis)

        // Slide paths left
        paths.attr('transform', null)
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration) + ')')
            .each('end', tick)

        // Remove oldest data point from each group
        for (var name in groups) {
            var group = groups[name]
            group.data.shift()
        }
    }

    tick()
    </script>
</body>
```

In this code new data is randomly generated. How i can i update it with my json data from api for real time.

Advance thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need an endpoint on API side which provides you with the data, and get that data using `fetch`. Then you need to pass the data through the function you have to write that will generate code similar to above.

That will be for getting data once. You can set that on interval, but best solution would be using socket.io, which needs to be implemented on the server side and in your js code.